# 11.10 won't boot cleanly on ASUS P8Z68-V/gen3

Tags: 11.10, boot, asus

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my computer and I have a problem booting it up. At boot, the system lands me in the EFI BIOS setup. From there, I specify that I want to boot from the first HD (where Ubuntu is installed), and the system boots.

Does anyone know how to make the system stop dropping me into the BIOS setup and just boot?

Motherboard: ASUS P8Z68-V/gen3
CPU: Intel core i5.
Disk: WD SATA 2TB.

Comment: I'm having trouble with that board. Can you help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/104378/boot-stuck-after-discovering-usb-devices

Answer (score 1):

Go to BIOS (F2 or F4 or DEL) then Go to Boot (or similar) section. Select first boot disk[HDD]. Save and exit.

Press the BIOS key or keys(F2 or F4 or DEL) [couple of times] at start-up your system to enter into BIOS.

Comment: Eventually I found out why this happened: I was feeding the water cooler from another set of power pins than those designated for the CPU fan. Moving to the CPU power, the system now boots cleanly.